# iOS Swift Multiple dimension arrays - compiliing takes ages. What should I change?

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array

I am new at swift. Never programming in ObjC before.
I have got a problem with iOS application, very simple-querying arrays via the picker.

I've got 4 multidimensional arrays like this one:

```
let Setting = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,2230],
    [0,0,0,0,0,2230,2157],
    [0,0,0,0,2230,2230,2085],
    [0,0,0,0,2230,2226,2017],
    [0,0,0,2230,2230,2222,1949],
    [0,0,2230,2230,2230,2218,1880],
    [0,0,2230,2230,2230,2135,1807],
    [0,2230,2230,2230,2230,2052,1735],
    [0,2230,2230,2230,2163,1965,1655],
    [2230,2230,2230,2230,2096,1878,1576],
    [2230,2230,2230,2191,2022,1793,1497],
    [2230,2230,2230,2096,1909,1708,1415],
    [2230,2230,2171,2003,1818,1623,1337],
    [2230,2230,2112,1910,1728,1539,1259],
    [2197,2214,2021,1820,1639,1454,1195],
    [2164,2199,1930,1731,1551,1370,1131],
    [2066,2104,1842,1645,1465,1302,1067],
    [1969,2010,1755,1559,1380,1234,1003],
    [1884,1902,1650,1460,1294,1155,0],
    [1799,1794,1546,1362,1209,1077,0],
    [1726,1665,1429,1259,1110,0,0],
    [1654,1537,1312,1157,1012,0,0],
    [1579,1422,1211,1059,0,0,0],
    [1505,1308,1111,961,0,0,0]
]
```

Everything works perfectly in the aplication if I remove these arrays (or use smaller e.g. 2 by 2). When I put it all at the proper place 
it will perform "indexing" all the time. Running my CPU at 100%

When I try to run - it never compils, even after 10 hours. Just stuck at "Compiling swift source files.

I searched for different data storage but I need these numbers in exact places. 
There is only small corelation between numbers so they cannot be changed into equation.

What I can do to compile this aplication?

Comment: If you search for *"expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time"* you'll find some similar questions. File a bug report at Apple!

Answer (score 2):

Swift it is having a hard time trying to deduct the array type. You just have to tell Swift it is an Array of Array of Ints:

```
let setting:[[Int]] = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,2230],
    [0,0,0,0,0,2230,2157],
    [0,0,0,0,2230,2230,2085],
    [0,0,0,0,2230,2226,2017],
    [0,0,0,2230,2230,2222,1949],
    [0,0,2230,2230,2230,2218,1880],
    [0,0,2230,2230,2230,2135,1807],
    [0,2230,2230,2230,2230,2052,1735],
    [0,2230,2230,2230,2163,1965,1655],
    [2230,2230,2230,2230,2096,1878,1576],
    [2230,2230,2230,2191,2022,1793,1497],
    [2230,2230,2230,2096,1909,1708,1415],
    [2230,2230,2171,2003,1818,1623,1337],
    [2230,2230,2112,1910,1728,1539,1259],
    [2197,2214,2021,1820,1639,1454,1195],
    [2164,2199,1930,1731,1551,1370,1131],
    [2066,2104,1842,1645,1465,1302,1067],
    [1969,2010,1755,1559,1380,1234,1003],
    [1884,1902,1650,1460,1294,1155,0],
    [1799,1794,1546,1362,1209,1077,0],
    [1726,1665,1429,1259,1110,0,0],
    [1654,1537,1312,1157,1012,0,0],
    [1579,1422,1211,1059,0,0,0],
    [1505,1308,1111,961,0,0,0]
]
```

Note: By Swift convention you should name your vars starting with a lowercase letter.