# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault 11

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a game with different levels stored in an Array like this :

```
let level1 = [

    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...],
    ... // UP TO 16

]
```

My screed is divided in 16 rows, so my level1 array is composed of 16 arrays. I use the level1 array to determined which image need to be loaded on row X on column X.

I generate the level like this :

```
for rows in 0...15 {

    for column in 0...nbColumns - 1 {

        let groundType = level1[rows][column]

        let ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "lvl1_groundType\(groundType)")
        ground.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        ground.position = CGPoint(x: 50 * CGFloat(column) + 50 / 2, y: 50 * 15 + 50 / 2)
        addChild(ground)

    }

}
```

The problem is that I get this error : `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault 11` because `level1[X].count` is to big (400). When I `level1[X].count` is equal to something like 20, there is no error and I can't run the game.

Have you a solution to this problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: It would help if you would include the exact error reported during the crash and identify the line number on which it occurred.

Comment: I found the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29816967/4529612 but thanks for your help ;)